# Получение типа переменной в динамическом режиме C++

Tags: типизация, c++

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить тип переменной при вводе ее в поток? Смотрел `typeid()`, но она выдает тип переменной, определенный при ее создании, мне нужен тип значения, который попадает в переменную в процессе работы программы. Например:

```
int a;  
cout<<"Input a";  
cin>>a; // Как здесь определить что a не равен char?
```

**UPD:** Не совсем правильно задал вопрос. Меня интересует как узнать какого типа значение в данный момент находится в потоке?

Comment: А кто его знает... Но можно поколдовать с лексическими анализаторами, или писаными вручную, как объясняется в соответствующих учебниках, или сгенерированными специальными инструментами. Первое, что приходит в голову -- flex (он бесплатный). Гуглить flex c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По внешнему виду. Т.е. написать парсер, который сканирует символы и по наличию цифр и скажем десятичной точки определяет, что в потоке находится действительное число. И т.п.

Вообще посмотрите формальные описания представления констант в языке и вперед. Еще вариант: изучить форматы scanf() и написать аналогичный разбор.

Comment: Да, это именно то, что и требовалось, далее уже разберусь ) Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ну если надо проверить, что `a` находится вне диапазона [-128,127], то выражение `a < -128 || a > 127` будет истинно, если значение `a` не помещается в байт. Хотя это вряд ли то, что Вы хотели, но сам подход кажется странным. C++, если не заморачиваться ООП фокусами, язык со статической типизацией. Соответственно значение `a` всегда будет `int`. Если Вы хотите определить, что у вас во входном потоке, то это совсем другая задача, парсинг, и решается она иначе.

Comment: Меня интересует то, что находится в потоке. Предположим, есть у меня какой-то метод класса с входными параметрами, а я в них передаю какое-то безобразие. Мне нужно знать какого типа параметры в данный момент у меня передаются.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, или вопрос задан некорректно?
Ну и ввел, например, пользователь число "10". Но вы же можете сами его перевести во что угодно. Получите, например, байт. И переводите хоть в char, хоть в int. 
Т.е. если у вас есть голый поток байт - то это может быть что угодно. Для этого и придумали протоколы =)

Comment: Согласен, не совсем верно задал вопрос: меня интересует какого типа значение в данный момент находится в потоке и как это узнать?